# using mupdf ndk-build error

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to use mupdf in android application.I am using windows 7 and cygwin terminal.I used make but it gave error and 
                      make NOX11=yes
execute successfully.

then i used ndk-build and it gives this error.

```
SharedLibrary  : libmupdf.so
c:/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_fontfile.o)(.text.pdf_lookup_builtin_font+0x18): unresolvable R_ARM_THM_CALL relocation against symbol `strcmp'
c:/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-binary.mk:378: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/libmupdf.so' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libmupdf.so] Error 1
```

please help me.I am new to android ndk.
Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems like a known issue. Try adding the line:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.4.3
```

to the file ..\android\jin\Application.mk. That will at least get rid of this particular error.

**EDIT**: Look here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35393 for more information

**UPDATE**:
mupdf world is a murky one. Even the version of NDK vis-a-vis the version of mupdf (http://mupdf.com/download/archive/) you use will determine what sort of errors or warnings you get. From my experience, mupdf-0.9 (+mupdf-thirdparty-2011-02-24.zip) behaves well with android-ndk-r6b, while mupdf-1.1 (+mupdf-thirdparty-2012-08-14.zip) will behave just fine with android-ndk-r8b.